# Rollback database operation

Tags: laravel, eloquent

Hello I have two tables in my database:

1. users
2. user_profiles

When i add a new user, data is also saved into the user_profile table.  I am considering a situation where for some reason the data is able to save into the user table but not the user_profile table.

I would want the data in the users table to be removed to avoid any broken records, since my user and user_profile table depend on each other.

What is the best way to achieve this?

Comment: http://laravel.com/docs/5.1/database#database-transactions

Answer (score 2):

You can use [database transactions](http://laravel.com/docs/5.1/database#database-transactions). The simplest way to use them is

```php
DB::transaction(function()
{
    // Do something that alters 'users' table
    // Do something that alters 'user_profiles' table
});
```

If any of the above operation fails (throws an exception) all the operations will be cancelled and your database will be untouched. If you need more control over the transaction, you can do this

```php
try {
    DB::beginTransaction();

    // Do something that alters 'users' table
    // Do something that alters 'user_profiles' table

    if($somethingWentWrong)
        throw new Exception('something went wrong');

    // Everything OK
    DB::commit();

} catch (\PDOException $e) {

    // something went wrong with the database
    DB::rollBack();
} catch (\Exception $e) {

    // something went wrong
    DB::rollBack();
}
```